# How I can inform unlocked thread (Monitor.Wait(), PulseAll() analog)

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

Tried to do so but got `SynchronizationLockException`.

```
static object blockObj = new object();
async void Method()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            bool status = Monitor.TryEnter(blockObj);
            Debug.WriteLine("Block status: " + (!status).ToString());
            if (!status)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(blockObj, 7000);//got SynchronizationLockException
                Debug.WriteLine("Other did the job");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Imitation of activity
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Monitor.PulseAll(blockObj);
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Monitor.IsEntered(blockObj))
                Monitor.Exit(blockObj);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to inform about the completion of the code execution?

Comment: You need to have lock acquired (monitor entered) for both `Wait` and `Pulse`. Now you are trying to `Wait` when you are not taken the lock (`status` = false) so it fails.

Comment: As an aside, mixing `Task` with `Monitor` is a recipe for trouble. If you're going to use threads, use threads. If you're going to use tasks, use something like [`AsyncMonitor`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncMonitor). (Or `TaskCompletionSource`/`*EventSlim`, if no condition is associated with the monitor.)

Comment: I need to inform exactly unlocked thread. Do you know how to do that properly?

Comment: You may be confused about how monitors work. Note that a `Monitor.Wait` call implicitly releases the lock, and reacquires it when the `Wait` returns. There is no need to do anything with a monitor that is not currently acquired, other than acquiring it. If you want to know if another thread performed work, set a variable and check its value inside the `lock` -- `PulseAll` only informs threads currently waiting. You'll have to describe your problem in more general terms if your current use of `Monitor` isn't achieving what you want.

Comment: The typical pattern is `lock (monitor) { while (!someConditionIsMet) monitor.Wait(); }` from one place, and `lock (monitor) { someConditionIsMet = true; Monitor.PulseAll(monitor); }` somewhere else. Threads not waiting on the monitor are "informed" by setting the condition variable (and then they will not wait).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to inform unlocked thread using [`Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx). Tried to go the other way using [`Thread.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx). Here's what I came up with:

```
public static void Synchronize()
{
    if (th1 == null || !th1.ThreadState.In(System.Threading.ThreadState.Running, System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Starting new thread...");
        th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr_sync));
        th1.Start();
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread is already started. Waiting for the end...");

    if (th1.Join(10000))
        Debug.WriteLine("Done");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Time out");
}
static void thr_sync()
{
    //Imitation of activity
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```